# Category Flat Data indexer process unknown error Magento 2

Tags: magento2, indexer

We are getting Integrity constraint violation: 1062 error when we are going to reindex in magento 2. Kindly see the error below and let me know if any update

```
Category Flat Data indexer process unknown error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '889' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_flat_store_1_tmp` (`row_id`,`entity_id`,`created_in`,`updated_in`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`position`,`level`,`children_count`,`store_id`,`all_children`,`automatic_sorting`,`available_sort_by`,`children`,`custom_apply_to_products`,`custom_design`,`custom_design_from`,`custom_design_to`,`custom_layout_update`,`custom_use_parent_settings`,`default_sort_by`,`description`,`disabled_children`,`display_mode`,`filter_price_range`,`image`,`include_in_menu`,`is_active`,`is_anchor`,`label_value`,`landing_page`,`level_column_count`,`meta_description`,`meta_keywords`,`meta_title`,`mp_meta_robots`,`name`,`page_layout`,`path_in_store`,`static_block_bottom_value`,`static_block_left_value`,`static_block_right_value`,`static_block_top_value`,`url_key`,`url_path`,`use_label`,`use_static_block`,`use_static_block_bottom`,`use_static_block_left`,`use_static_block_right`,`use_static_block_top`,`use_thumbail`) VALUES
```

Comment: Try to restart your mysql using this command in the shell `sudo service mysql restart` and try again `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: @UsmanYousaf this is not working for us. Kindly check this once again and it is Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '889'.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this command in sequence.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento ind:rein
```